# StringIO replacement that works with bytes instead of strings?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, stringio

Is there any replacement for python `StringIO` class, one that will work with `bytes` instead of strings?

It may not be obvious but if you used StringIO for processing binary data you are out of luck with Python 2.7 or newer.

Comment: It is not obvious what your problem is. Please demonstrate your alleged problem by showing code that works in 2.6 but not in 2.7. Or see my answer.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html?highlight=bytesio#io.BytesIO).

As [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480012/577088) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481034/577088) pointed out, you can indeed use `StringIO` in 2.7, but `BytesIO` is a good choice for forward-compatibility.

Comment: How does one _write_ to an `io.BytesIO` object? I just get the message `TypeError: descriptor 'write' for '_io.BytesIO' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object`.

Answer (score 12):

In Python 2.6/2.7, the [io](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html?highlight=io.stringio#module-io) module is intended to be used for compatibility with Python 3.X.  From the docs:

> New in version 2.6.
>
> The io module provides the Python
>   interfaces to stream handling. Under
>   Python 2.x, this is proposed as an
>   alternative to the built-in file
>   object, but in Python 3.x it is the
>   default interface to access files and
>   streams.
>
> Note Since this module has been
>   designed primarily for Python 3.x, you
>   have to be aware that all uses of
>   “bytes” in this document refer to the
>   str type (of which bytes is an alias),
>   and all uses of “text” refer to the
>   unicode type. Furthermore, those two
>   types are not interchangeable in the
>   io APIs.

In Python versions earlier than 3.X the [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html?highlight=stringio#module-StringIO) module contains the legacy version of StringIO, which unlike `io.StringIO` can be used in pre-2.6 versions of Python:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> s=StringIO.StringIO()
>>> s.write('hello')
>>> s.getvalue()
'hello'
>>> import io
>>> s=io.StringIO()
>>> s.write('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'str'
>>> s.write(u'hello')
5L
>>> s.getvalue()
u'hello'
```

Answer (score 8):

You say: "*It may not be obvious but if you used StringIO for processing binary data you are out of luck with Python 2.7 or newer*".

It is not obvious because it is not true.

**If you have code that works on 2.6 or earlier, it continues to work on 2.7**. Unedited screen dump (Windows Command prompt window wrapping at col 80 and all):

```
C:\Users\John>\python26\python -c"import sys,StringIO;s=StringIO.StringIO();s.wr
ite('hello\n');print repr(s.getvalue()), sys.version"
'hello\n' 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

C:\Users\John>\python27\python -c"import sys,StringIO;s=StringIO.StringIO();s.wr
ite('hello\n');print repr(s.getvalue()), sys.version"
'hello\n' 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

**If you need to write code that runs on 2.7 and 3.x, use the `BytesIO` class in the `io` module.**

**If you need/want a single codebase that supports 2.7, 2.6, ... and 3.x, you will need to work a bit harder.** Using the [six](http://packages.python.org/six/) module should help a lot.