# passing a plot from matpotlib to a flask view

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I am trying to plot some values and pass them to a Flask template. I tried using this method: [How to render and return plot to view in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492197/how-to-render-and-return-plot-to-view-in-flask)

Unfortunately I get this error.

> TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

I got through to the template when changed the img type to BytesIO, but still it wouldn't show the plot.

I am dead in the water here, can anybody help?

Here is my plot.py

```
@app.route('/plot', methods=['POST']) # I use POST because I will introduce user specified data
def plot():
if request.method == 'POST':

    img = io.BytesIO()
    x = [1,2,3,6,7]
    y = [4,6,7,9,10]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    plt.savefig("../xxxx.png") # this works just fine
    img.seek(0)
    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())
    return render_template('plot.html', plot_url=plot_url)
```

And this is plot.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}


<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url }}" width="20" height="20" alt="graph">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479100/python-stringio-replacement-that-works-with-bytes-instead-of-strings

Comment: Thank you, yes I saw this post but it did not solve my problem. Changing the type to BytesIO solves the incompatibility, but I still don't see the image in the browser. I seems to me that the problem might lie in the encoding, because when i tried to savefig to a file it worked just fine.

Comment: Could you post some of the code in question? I could answer better if I saw where the error was arising from.

Comment: I edited my initial post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Python version are you using? On Python 3.x `base64.b64encode()` returns `bytes` object and that's why it probably fails. You need to decode it into a string before passing it to Flask. Also, you should URL-escape your base64-encoded string since you're printing it inside of your HTML, something like:

```
import urllib.parse

# ...

img = io.BytesIO()  # create the buffer
plt.savefig(img, format='png')  # save figure to the buffer
img.seek(0)  # rewind your buffer
plot_data = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode()) # base64 encode & URL-escape
return render_template('plot.html', plot_url=plot_data)
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked! I am indeed using Python 3. Thank you!

Comment: Just a small suggestion. I think in Python 3.x we need to use import urllib.parse instead of import urllib

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal - Updated, thanks for catching it. 